# Ignore device orientation on mobile

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, screen-orientation

I have a Vue js component that triggers a method every time the orientation of the device changes to landscape. I have used `window.addEventListener("orientationchange", functionName, false);` to trigger the method.

This works perfectly fine on mobile when the device orientation is set to auto-rotate, but it doesn't when the orientation is set to portrait.

Is there any way to overwrite the portrait mode and detect when the device is rotating in order to trigger the method?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the app to fullscreen mode and then calling  `window.screen.orientation.lock("any");` did the trick.